# .docx with a line that isn't a border

Tags: microsoft-word, documents

I can't select this line and I can't delete it.

It's not a border also.

[image]

How to delete it?

Comment: Note: I can see at least TWO lines (black), which one is it that you have a problem with?

Answer (score 1):

That's the line that automatically placed over footnotes to separate them from the main body of the document.

Assuming Word 2013:

1. Click the **View** tab.
2. Put the document in **Draft** view.
3. Click the *8References** tab.
4. Click **Show Notes** in the Footnotes ribbon section.
5. A *"Footnotes"* pane should appear.
6. Select **Footnote Separator** from the drop-down on the Footnotes pane title bar.
7. Select (double-click) and delete the line.
8. Switch back to **Print Layout** view (via the **View** tab), and the line should now be gone.

Answer (score 0):

If Techie007's answer doesn't work...

Try this:

- Select text that is on BOTH SIDES of the item you wish to remove.
- Go to the Table border settings and select "None" for borders.

I experienced a similar issue in the Outlook 2007 editor (Word!) just yesterday.